# Mongodb agent are not able to send metric to cloud manager

Tags: mongodb-atlas

I am running atlas mongo on EC2 machine using docker compose as mentioned here:
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/cli/stable/atlas-cli-deploy-docker/

then I installed the MongoDB agent on the same EC2 instance but I'm unable to see any monitoring data in Cloud Manager.

[image]

Opening the EC2 instance to all IPs (0.0.0.0) allows monitoring in Cloud Manager, but this compromises security. What would be the best approach to ensure secure connectivity between Cloud Manager and my EC2 instance while maintaining security?